# Transforming multi-dimensional array into grouped array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have a multidimensional array as below (columns) and need it transformed into array of objects forming a grouped hierarchal structure to construct a table header.

Each values has to be nested in the order of index and also grouped. Any pointers how this can be achieved ?

```
var columns = [
        ["Price", "Australia", "Melbourne", "Comfort Hotel & Spa"],
        ["Price", "Costa Rica", "Tamarindo", "Summer Isle Hotel"],
        ["Stars", "Fiji", "Suva", "Crescent Resort1"],
        ["Stars", "Fiji", "Suva", "Crescent Resort2"],
    ];

//need it to be transformed into structure like this
var transformedArray = [{
    Header: 'Price',
    columns: [{
        Header: 'Australia',
        columns: [{
            Header: 'Melbourne',
            columns: [{
                Header: 'Comfort Hotel & Spa',
                value: 'Price-Australia-Melbourne-Comfort Hotel & Spa'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        Header: 'Costa Rica',
        columns: [{
            Header: 'Tamarindo',
            columns: [{
                Header: 'Summer Isle Hotel',
                value: 'Price-Costa Rica-Tamarindo-Summer Isle Hotel'
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    Header: 'Stars',
    columns: [{
        Header: 'Fiji',
        columns: [{
            Header: 'Suva',
            columns: [{
                    Header: 'Crescent Resort1',
                    value: 'Stars-Fiji-suva-Crescent Resort1'
                },
                {
                    Header: 'Crescent Resort2',
                    value: 'Stars-Fiji-suva-Crescent Resort2'
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `reduce()` calls to build the structure of each object, reserving out the last element of each array to push into the innermost `columns` array returned by the inner `reduce()`

```js
var input = [["Price", "Australia", "Melbourne", "Comfort Hotel & Spa"], ["Price", "Costa Rica", "Tamarindo", "Summer Isle Hotel"], ["Stars", "Fiji", "Suva", "Crescent Resort1"], ["Stars", "Fiji", "Suva", "Crescent Resort2"],];

const output = input.reduce((a, arr) => {
  const
    leafValue = arr.join('-'),
    leafHeader = arr.pop();

  const inner = arr.reduce((b, e) => (
    b.push({ Header: e, columns: [] }), b[b.length - 1].columns), a)

  inner.push({ Header: leafHeader, value: leafValue });
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```